# Distributed Application Migration - To new HA MQ architecture

Tags: java, migration, ibm-mq

I am a developer of J2EE based web applications. The current MQ architecture of have a single Q Manager is getting migrated to High Availability IBM-MQ architecture.

Current State
1. the application writes a message on to a Queue and read the response (there are instance both where the messaging is synchronous and asynchronous too)
2. The Q manager is installed local on the websphere

To Be state
1. the MQ architecture is to have 2 active active q managers listening to messages

Question
1. what would be the distributed applications code changes to support this new MQ architecture
2. would the Java EE application be rewritten to write into 2 Q Managers at a time?

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: Is this IBM MQ? What version?

Comment: Yes JoshMc this is IBM MQ.  Moving to MQ 10

Comment: MQ v9.0 LTS and v9.0.2 CD are the latest.  Can you confirm if you are looking to leverage either the Multi Instance feature of MQ where you have a single queue manager that runs on two hosts with one in a standby mode to startup if the other fails or a hardware cluster software like VCS or RHCS?

Comment: Hi Josh, I am not an MQ expert .. but from what I hear its going to be 2 Q Managers which are in active active state. And there will be a netscalar installed on top of these Qmanagers to perform load balancing.       We are looking for code changes that a Java application has to perform when moving from a single Q Manager to 2 active active QManagers

Comment: This brings up issues if for instance you are connected to QM1 and send out a request message, and before the response is received on QM1 you get disconnected, the next time you connect depending on how the load balancer is configured you could be connected to QM2 and that would leave the reply message orphaned on QM1.  Load balancers can be setup to do things like always direct the same source IP to the same destination if the destination is still available.

Comment: Load balancing clusters are typically not a way to achieve HA. If you want HA, you should be looking at multi instance QMs or some external HA manager, like PowerHA. A well configured multi instance or PowerHA solution should be transparent to the application code. And to your 2. question: duplicating messages is one of the worst things that can happen in a MQ infrastructure.